# Xcode: Export Storyboard to image

Tags: xcode, printing, storyboard

I need a huge Xcode Storyboard in an image format so we can plot it on a plotter and mount it on one of the office walls. I have tried exporting it, but that only allows you to use storyboard format. Just trying to print it doesn't work either, as Xcode cannot print storyboard files.

Any solutions short of taking several screenshots and sowing them together will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here it is the best hack I found :

Using a applescript it is possible to resize Xcode beyond screen size (it is possible even manually) :

```
set front_app to "Xcode"

tell application front_app
    activate
    set bounds of front window to {0, 0, 5000, 1000}
end tell
```

The maximum height seems to be the screen height, but it is possible to have the width much bigger than the screen's width.

Afterwards with a screen capture software it is possible to capture the entire Xcode window(beyond screen's bounds).

In my test, I made 5 files for a 5000px x 5000px image. It is not the best option but it works. Hopefully Apple will add the print function or maybe somebody can automate the screen capture/stitch part.

Comment: Nice one. It is kind of crappy that you can make the height of a window bigger than the screen.... I suddenly despise it...

Comment: "that you can make the height of a window bigger than the screen." - can you? this screen does not got the windows bigger than screen for me, despite that I've changed 1000 to 5000...

Comment: Doesn't work very well if you are using more than one monitor.  You get one file per display.

Comment: Very nice – I found that I wasn't able to increase the vertical size beyond that of the screen. I got around this by full screening xCode before running the script.

Comment: To take a capture after resizing Xcode, use CMD + Shift + 4 and the space after.